# Equality with matrices

Tags: matrices

I need prove the following:

$(\mu-\lambda)(D-\mu I)^{-1}(D-\lambda I)^{-1}=(D-\mu I)^{-1}-(D-\lambda I)^{-1}$

where $D$ is a matrix, $I$ is the indentity matrix and $\mu,\lambda$ reals.

Thanks!

Comment: $D$ is any matrix, or a diagonal matrix?

Comment: $D$ is any matrix

Answer (score 1):

Clear denominators.  Be a little careful with commutativity issues (and sort of that these aren't really denominators, but that's not a meaningful issue).  For that point, remember: which matrices commute with all other matrices?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you show me more details? I do not see how to get the result